# HTML 5 VIDEO TAG - STATIC NOISE

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html5-video, mp4, webm

I noticed there is a  difference between Chrome and Firefox. I display some videos using the HTML 5 video tag. When I played a video in Chrome, I didn't hear any static background noise; in the Firefox browser, the video is OK but contains a static noise.

The page has 8 links that open a new window.
Here is a sample of the code:

```
<a
    href="HS-Health_Safety/handling-caustic-safely.html" 
    onclick="positionedPopup(this.href,'myWindow','1278','810','100','200','yes');return false"
>
    Handling Caustic Safely
</a>
```

Each embed page contains code like this:

```
<video width="1278" height="810" controls> 
<source src="10-Step_Cleaning_Process/PC9.8_STEP_8_Post_Job_Review.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="10-Step_Cleaning_Process/PC9.8_STEP_8_Post_Job_Review.mp4.webm" type="video/webm"> 
</video>
```

**What I've tried:**
I played the video alone, but there was no static noise. How do I remove this noise from Firefox?

Comment: Is this on any video (MP4/WebM) that is played? Or some have worked? Do you have a web space to show a demo page that can be tested on Firefox versus Chrome? It would be helpful to also tell us what version of Firefox and what O.S you're using (maybe it's a Windows issue but does not happen on Mac or Android? etc)... Hopefully someone can answer your problem.

Comment: I'm asking about the static noise, does it always happen no matter which video file you test? I'm trying if it works okay with some video files...

Comment: @VC.One
Is this on any video (MP4/WebM that is played? The page has 8 links that open a new window. 

Here is a sample of the code 

 <a href="HS-Health_Safety/handling-caustic-safely.html" onclick="positionedPopup(this.href,'myWindow','1278','810','100','200','yes');return false">Handling Caustic Safely</a> 

Each page contains  thi
 
<video width="1278" height="810" controls>
  <source src="10-Step_Cleaning_Process/PC9.8_STEP_8_Post_Job_Review.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="10-Step_Cleaning_Process/PC9.8_STEP_8_Post_Job_Review.mp4.webm" type="video/webm"> 
 </video>

Comment: Some have worked? 
When playing a video in Firefox, every video has a static noise.

Both browsers are a current version. 

I am not sure whether it's a Window or Mac issue.

Comment: I'm asking about the static noise, does it always happen no matter which video file you test? I'm trying if it works okay with some video files...

The static noise only happens in the Firefox browser. Each 8-page contains static noise.
The video itself does not have static noise.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on Windows Firefox. Does this [test video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4) link have static noise for you when opened in your Firefox?

Comment: @VC.One
The links on the main page have no static noise. The static noise is coming from the embed page. I do not see any invalid tags here:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CLEANING PROCESS ⇄ STEP 1 SCHEDULING</title>
</head>

<body>
<video width="1278" height="810" controls> 
<source src="10-Step_Cleaning_Process/PC9.8_STEP_8_Post_Job_Review.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="10-Step_Cleaning_Process/PC9.8_STEP_8_Post_Job_Review.mp4.webm" type="video/webm"> 
</video>
</body></html>

Comment: **(1)** You're going to have to put an example page online. I **cannot reproduce** your issue. I tested your shown code at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) (I used `movie.mp4` as the video link). Their video does not play with noise in Firefox... **(2)** What happens if you remove the second file ending `.mp4.webm`? The `<source>` should be just one MP4, does the static noise stop now?